# 'file' is a type and cannot be used as an expression Error

Tags: vb.net, encryption, syntax, error-handling

I want to create a encrypter which encrypt list of files using Rijndael, That's why I created a basic application with listbox which list all given files from a  particular drive. Using following code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Public Sub DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String)
    Try
        For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
            For Each file In Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.pdf")
                lstFilesFound.Items.Add(file)
                FileToBase64(lstFilesFound.Items.Add(file))
            Next
            DirSearch(dir)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DirSearch("c:\")

End Sub
```

And it work as expected but when i try to merge this code with this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12092/Encrypt-Decrypt-Files-in-VB-NET-Using-Rijndael

It gives error of 
'file' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: why are you adding the file to the listbox twice? `lstFilesFound.Items.Add()` returns an integer.  If `FileToBase64` wants a filename, that call will fail and it also means `Option Strict` is not on.

Answer (score 2):

You are Importing a Namespace that contains a type named File.  This causes a conflict in your For Each statement.  This is an example of where Hungarian Notation is useful.  Update your For Each statement to this:

```
        For Each objFile In Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.pdf")
            lstFilesFound.Items.Add(objFile)
            FileToBase64(lstFilesFound.Items.Add(objFile))
        Next
```

Comment: Error 2 'objFile' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. C:\Users\GM\Downloads\Compressed\EncryptFile_src\frmMain.vb 805 26 EncryptFile

Comment: SO answer box needs Intellisense ;)

Comment: I looked at that link.  You need to have lstFIlesFound.Items.Add(objFile) and FileToBase64(lstFilesFound.Items.Add(objFile))

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
        For Each fi as File In Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.pdf")
            lstFilesFound.Items.Add(fi)
            FileToBase64(lstFilesFound.Items.Add(fi))
        Next
```

You can't pass FILE as the add() parameter because it isn't instantiated.  Instead use the code above.

Comment: `Shared Function GetFiles(path As String) As String( )` there are no `File` objects returned.  And `File` is all Shared/static methods - you never instantiate them.

Comment: You're  right.  I guess what I mentioned to say was that the add method is expecting an instance of an object but file (as he was using it there) was a type and therefore not an instantce.